# Trying to call by click uibutton event move to another secondviewcontroller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I am trying to call by click uibutton event move to another `secondviewcontroller` by programming

```
(IBAction)button:(id)sender
{
  UIViewController *homecon=[[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"loginscreen" bundle:NULL];

    [self segueForUnwindingToViewController:homecon fromViewController:homecon identifier:@"loginscreen"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homecon animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one if you are in **navigation controller**

```
(IBAction)button:(id)sender 
{

    ViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"loginscreen" bundle:NULL];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

Otherwise simply this

```
(IBAction)button:(id)sender 
{
     ViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"loginscreen" bundle:NULL];
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```